# Get database subject sequence with mismatches using NCBI command line blast

Tags: blast, ncbi

I am using Blast command line. The query (length 9) is ADZTZZETK, but when blasted against database sequence, it gives alignment of length 8 (ADZTZZET:ADZTZZET). It means that last, 9th, character of query sequence, K, is mis-matched with database sequence. However I still want to get the 9th mis-matched character of database sequence. Could someone tell me which option I should use in command line blast for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think you can get the full query or subject sequence from BLAST. If you look under the `outfmt` options in the [command-line documentation](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK279675/) the closest option is `sseq`, which says `Aligned part of subject sequence`. If you can download the database in `FASTA` format, then you can parse that file separately and get the subject sequence.

Comment: Thank you very much sailor. I did post-processing to get those missing positions.